# Create menu flyout using c#

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I want to create menu flyout using C#. I tried this

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add("Rotate");
l.Add("Scale");
l.Add("Bring to Front");
l.Add("Send to Back");
MenuFlyout m = new MenuFlyout();
MenuFlyoutItem mn = l;
m.Items.Add(mn);
```

It gives error,how to do that?

Comment: `MenuFlyoutItem mn = l;` is the offending line. I don't have Windows 8.1 so can't prove "correct" code, but it looks as though you should be adding a number of `MenuFlyoutItem` to your `MenuFlyout`, one for each item in your list.

Comment: can you provide little code ?

Comment: I could guess, but since I am unable to compile it I could not be sure that it would work. Your example in your answer below is what I would have imagined, but without being able to prove it I was not willing to propose it as an answer.

Answer (score 9):

This code works:

```
MenuFlyout m = new MenuFlyout();
MenuFlyoutItem mn = new MenuFlyoutItem();
mn.Text = "Item 1";
m.Items.Add(mn);
m.ShowAt((FrameworkElement)sender);
```

Comment: I'm assuming that your use of `sender` implies that this code is in an event handler. That being the case, you should do a check on the type of `sender` before relying on it, e.g. add `FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement; if (element != null) { ...` before the block.